# Normalized Mutual Information in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, cluster-analysis

Is that possible to implement normalized mutual information in Tensorflow? I was wondering if I can do that and if I will be able to differentiate it. Let's say that I have predictions P and labels Y in two different tensors. Is there an easy way to use normalized mutual information?

I want to do something similar to this:

https://course.ccs.neu.edu/cs6140sp15/7_locality_cluster/Assignment-6/NMI.pdf

Comment: If you use continuous predictions from the model, carefully normalize them (e.g., using softmax) so that they interpret as the probability of being in each class, then the answer is yes and they can be differentiated. If you discretize the outputs, they are not differentiable. Google cross-entropy loss to get an idea of how to calculate conditional entropy between continuous P and discrete Y.

Comment: I think you misundersood my question. I want to make a prediction inside my graph based on clustering labels and true labels, not based on my logits and true labels. 
In order to illustrate this:
argmax(logits) = [4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1]
argmax(labels) = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]

In this example cross entropy would be 0, however, clustering is still very good because we have put the same class instances in the same cluster. Normalized mutual information gives me this, but I could not figure out how to use it in Tensorflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume your clustering method gives probability predictions/membership functions `p(c|x)`, e.g., `p(c=1|x)` is the probability of `x` in the first cluster. Assume y is the ground truth class label for `x`.

The normalized mutual information is [image].

The entropy H(Y) can be estimated following this thread: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/338719/calculating-clusters-entropy-python

By definition, the entropy H(C) is [image], where [image].

The conditional mutual information [image] where [image], and [image].

All terms involving integral can be estimated using sampling, i.e., average over training samples. The overall NMI is differentiable.

I did not misunderstand your question. I was assuming you used a neural network model which outputs logits as you did not provide any info. Then you need to normalise the logits to get `p(c|x)`.

There may be other ways to estimate NMI, but if you discretize the output of whatever model you use, you cannot differentiate them.

---

TensorFlow code

Assume we have label matrix `p_y_on_x` and cluster predictions `p_c_on_x`. Each row of them corresponds to an observation `x`; each column corresponds to the probability of `x` in each class and cluster (so each row sums up to one). Further assume uniform probability for `p(x)` and `p(x|y)`.

Then NMI can then be estimated as below:

```
p_y = tf.reduce_sum(p_y_on_x, axis=0, keepdim=True) / num_x  # 1-by-num_y
h_y = -tf.reduce_sum(p_y * tf.math.log(p_y))
p_c = tf.reduce_sum(p_c_on_x, axis=0) / num_x  # 1-by-num_c
h_c = -tf.reduce_sum(p_c * tf.math.log(p_c))
p_x_on_y = p_y_on_x / num_x / p_y  # num_x-by-num_y
p_c_on_y = tf.matmul(p_c_on_x, p_x_on_y, transpose_a=True)  # num_c-by-num_y
h_c_on_y = -tf.reduce_sum(tf.reduce_sum(p_c_on_y * tf.math.log(p_c_on_y), axis=0) * p_y)
i_y_c = h_c - h_c_on_y
nmi = 2 * i_y_c / (h_y + h_c)
```

In practice, please be very careful on the probabilities as they should be positive to avoid numeric overflow in `tf.math.log`.

Please comment if you find any mistakes.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I still do not know what Tensorflow code should I use to get this. Suppose that I have two tensors named "labels" and "logits". What is the code to calculate the NMI?

Comment: I cannot realize what does the variable label refer to in line 5.

Comment: @Siavash My fault. Initially, I used `label` and `cluster` then I thought `p_y_on_x` and `p_c_on_x` would make it more clear. I have revised that part and verified that when `p_y_on_x` and `p_c_on_x` are independent, `nmi` is close to zero.

Comment: Thank you. When I give the same vector as labels and predictions, I should get 1, but that does not happen. Do you know what is the reason?

Comment: @Siavash I assume by "same vector" you mean `p_y_on_x=p_c_on_x`, which is different from `p(y=c|x)=1`. The latter means `y` and `c` has exactly the same observations. In this case, each sample `x` is assigned to one class and the same cluster with probability 1. If you initialize each `p_y_on_x` with a single 1 and the rest zero, e.g. [1e-6, 1e-6, 1, 1e-6] (small scalar here to avoid numeric issue), and assign `p_c_on_x=p_y_on_x`, you should be able to get `nmi` very close to 1.